# Why width number can not work after a "#" in printf format?

Tags: c, printf

I wanna to get "0x08" for number 8, but when I use "%#02x", I only get 0x8:

```
int i = 0x08;
printf("%#02x", i); // only print 0x8, not 0x08
```

It seems like width number can not work after a "#" in format string.
Is there any better way to print what I want other than use "0x%02x"?

Comment: I routinely use `0x%.8X` as that gets me the layout I prefer, and it isn't attainable via any other mechanism.

Comment: you do realize that the leading `0x` is just text  and has nothing to do with what is printed by the actual format specification

Answer (score 6):

The field width includes the "alternative prefix" requested by `#`.

So you could use: `printf("%#04x", i);` to get the desired effect.  Personally I'd prefer `"0x%02x"` as you mentioned already.

Another way, recommended by @R.. ,  would be to use *minimum precision* instead of *field width*. For integers, the precision excludes the prefix, and is always zero-padded if necessary, so the code would be `printf("%#.2x", i);`.

For integer specifiers such as `x`, the number after the `.` is a minimum precision - longer numbers will not be truncated. This differs from the behaviour of `.` for floating point and strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ^^

Comment: `%#.2x` is preferable. Don't use width when you mean precision.